# Understanding piping: PHP -c

Tags: php, shell

I am having trouble understanding this Linux command:
`php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -c php.ini`

It appears the first part `php -r` is piping to `php -c`. But it appears `php.ini` is being *read*.

Where can I find out more about php command options and they mean (-v and -c), and thus find out what the command is doing?

Comment: What's wrong with the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)?

Comment: @JoeHabadas I am a PHP novice. How did you find it? I googled "PHP options", "PHP -c", "PHP -v" and did not find it.

Comment: `php --help`, `man php` ... you don't even need internet for that.

Comment: I never received any feedback regarding the answer I left; did it solve your problem? If it did, marking it as accepted would be appreciated; thanks.

Comment: @miken32 I read your answer just now - thanks very much. Both answers actually helped me resolve my problem. As the system won't let me accept multiple answers, I simply upvoted both.

Answer (score 3):

From `man php`:

> OPTIONS
>         --interactive
>         -a             Run  PHP  interactively. This lets you enter snippets of
>                        PHP code that directly get executed. When readline  sup‐
>                        port  is  enabled  you  can edit the lines and also have
>                        history support.
>
> ```
>   --bindpath address:port|port
>   -b address:port|port
>                  Bind Path for external FASTCGI Server mode (CGI only).
>
>   --no-chdir
>   -C             Do not chdir to the script's directory (CGI only).
>
>   --no-header
>   -q             Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).
>
>   --timing count
>   -T count       Measure execution time of script  repeated  count  times
>                  (CGI only).
>
>   --php-ini path|file
>   -c path|file   Look  for  php.ini file in the directory path or use the
>                  specified file
>
>   --no-php-ini
>   -n             No php.ini file will be used
>
>   --define foo[=bar]
>   -d foo[=bar]   Define INI entry foo with value bar
>
>   -e             Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
>
>   --file file
>   -f file        Parse and execute file
>
>   --help
>   -h             This help
>
>   --hide-args
>   -H             Hide script name (file) and  parameters  (args...)  from
>                  external  tools.  For  example  you may want to use this
>                  when a php script is started as a daemon and the command
>                  line contains sensitive data such as passwords.
>
>   --info
>   -i             PHP information and configuration
>
>   --syntax-check
>   -l             Syntax check only (lint)
>
>   --modules
>   -m             Show compiled in modules
>
>   --run code
>   -r code        Run PHP code without using script tags '<?..?>'
>
>   --process-begin code
>   -B begin_code  Run PHP begin_code before processing input lines
>
>   --process-code code
>   -R code        Run PHP code for every input line
>
>   --process-file file
>   -F file        Parse and execute file for every input line
>
>   --process-end code
>   -E end_code    Run PHP end_code after processing all input lines
>
>   --syntax-highlight
>   -s             Output HTML syntax highlighted source
>
>   --server addr:port
>   -S addr:port   Start built-in web server on the given local address and
>                  port
>
>   --docroot docroot
>   -t docroot     Specify the document root to be used by the built-in web
>                  server
>
>   --version
>   -v             Version number
>
>   --strip
>   -w             Output source with stripped comments and whitespace
>
>   --zend-extension file
>   -z file        Load Zend extension file
>
>   args...        Arguments  passed  to  script.  Use '--' args when first
>                  argument starts with '-' or script is read from stdin
>
>   --rfunction    name
>   --rf           name Shows information about function name
>
>   --rclass       name
>   --rc           name Shows information about class name
>
>   --rextension   name
>   --re           name Shows information about extension name
>
>   --rzendextension
>                  name
>   --rz           name Shows information about Zend extension name
>
>   --rextinfo     name
>   --ri           name Shows configuration for extension name
>
>   --ini          Show configuration file names
> ```

From php.net:

> Usage: php [options] [-f]  [--] [args...]    php [options] -r
>    `[--] [args...]    php [options] [-B ] -R  [-E
>   ] [--] [args...]    php [options] [-B ] -F
>    [-E ] [--] [args...]    php [options] -- [args...]
>
>   php [options] -a`
>
> -a               Run interactively   -c | Look for
>   php.ini file in this directory   -n               No php.ini file will
>   be used   -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'   -e 
>   Generate extended information for debugger/profiler   -f 
>   Parse and execute .   -h               This help   -i
>   PHP information   -l               Syntax check only (lint)   -m
>   Show compiled in modules   -r         Run PHP  without
>   using script tags    -B   Run PHP 
>   before processing input lines   -R         Run PHP  for
>   every input line   -F         Parse and execute  for every
>   input line   -E     Run PHP  after processing all
>   input lines   -H               Hide any passed arguments from external
>   tools.   -S : Run with built-in web server.   -t 
>   Specify document root  for built-in web server.   -s
>   Output HTML syntax highlighted source.   -v               Version
>   number   -w               Output source with stripped comments and
>   whitespace.   -z         Load Zend extension .
>
> args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first
>   argument
>                      starts with - or script is read from stdin
>
> --ini            Show configuration file names
>
> --rf       Show information about function .   --rc
>         Show information about class .   --re 
>   Show information about extension .   --rz       Show
>   information about Zend extension .   --ri       Show
>   configuration for extension .

**Edit:**

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -c php.ini
```

This command runs the file https://getcomposer.org/installer using php.ini in the current directory as the config file. The same can be achieved with

```
php -r "require('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" -c php.ini
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you include what you think the command is doing?

Answer (score 2):

Running `php` with the `-c` option simply tells it where to find its configuration file. The `-r` option tells it to run the code provided.

What your command is doing is fetching some remote PHP code and then piping it to another PHP process to be executed.

Unless you happen to have a special configuration requirement (and have a `php.ini` file in the current directory) the `-c` option isn't needed.

I don't recommend doing this, by the way. It's an unnecessary risk to run unknown code on your machine, even it it appears to be coming from a known source.